# Using stringstream: Only working for first value

Tags: c++, get, stringstream, peek

I am trying to use stringstream with peek() and get(n). It is only working for the first value, Name, and then gives empty values for everything except weight, which gives 0 (when printing out with cout).

```
    stringstream ss;
    ss.str("John Smith, Toyota, 160, brown blue, orange");
    //Extract into these variables:
    string Name = "" ;
    string car = "" ;
    int weight = 0;
    string hairColor = "";
    string eyeColor = "";
    string favoriteColor = "";





while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            Name += temp;
        }
while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            car += temp;
        }
while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            weight += temp;
        }
while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            hairColor += temp;
        }
while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            eyeColor += temp;
        }
while (ss.peek () != ',')
        {
            char temp;
            ss. get(temp);
            favoriteColor += temp;
        }


cout << "Name is: " << Name << endl;
cout << "car is: " << car << endl;
cout << "weight is: " << weight << endl;
cout << "Hair color is: " << hairColor << endl;
cout << "Eye color is: " << eyeColor << endl;
cout << "Favorite color is: " << favoriteColor << endl;
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `ss.peek() == ','` becomes true at the end of the first loop.

Comment: so do I have to reset it to false? how do I do that?

Comment: Easy solution is to put `ss.ignore()` after the closing brace of each loop.

Comment: Common mistake: you use C++ streams wrong, if you do not check the state of an extraction

Comment: Easy solution is to do ss.ignore() at the end of each loop –  0x499602D2         this works, but I meant to write a white space for one of the commas above. How to I do ss.peek () != ',' for white space? As in ss.peek () != '(white space)'?

Comment: @JCoder You don't do that, you simply use `ss >> Name >> car >> etc`. The extractor `>>` delimits by whitespace.

Comment: 0x499602D2 I want to use while loops. I updated the code above to show what I mean. Instead of "brown, blue", it now reads "brown blue".

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that after the first loop the continuation condition is `false`, so none of the following loops, with the same continuation condition, do anything.

However, the usual way to extract an item is to use the `getline` function, where you can specify an arbitrary delimiter character instead of newline.

Doing this properly is a bit involved:

```
#include <iomanip>              // std::setw
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>            // std::runtime_error, std::exception
#include <stdlib.h>             // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <sstream>              // std::istringstream
using namespace std;

auto fail( const string& s ) -> bool { throw runtime_error( s ); }

auto get_string( istream& stream, const char delimiter = ',' )
    -> string
{
    while( stream.peek() == ' ' )
    {
        stream.get();
    }
    string result;
    getline( stream, result, delimiter )
        || fail( "get_string: failed to extract text" );
    return result;
}

template< class Type >
auto get( istream& stream, const char delimiter = ',' )
    -> Type
{
    istringstream conversion_stream( get_string( stream, delimiter ) );
    Type result;
    conversion_stream >> result
        || fail( "get: failed to convert text to value" );
    return result;
}

template<>
auto get<string>( istream& stream, const char delimiter )
    -> string
{ return get_string( stream, delimiter ); }

template< class Type >
void display( const char name[], const Type& value )
{
    cout << setw( 15 ) << name << " = " << value << endl;
}

#define DISPLAY( x ) display( #x, x )
void cpp_main()
{
    istringstream data_stream( "John Smith, Toyota, 160, brown, blue, orange" );

    const auto name             = get<string>( data_stream );
    const auto car              = get<string>( data_stream );
    const auto weight           = get<int>( data_stream );
    const auto hairColor        = get<string>( data_stream );
    const auto eyeColor         = get<string>( data_stream );
    const auto favoriteColor    = get<string>( data_stream );

    DISPLAY( name );
    DISPLAY( car );
    DISPLAY( weight );
    DISPLAY( hairColor );
    DISPLAY( eyeColor );
    DISPLAY( favoriteColor );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    try
    {
        cpp_main();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( const exception& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ss.peek() == ','` becomes true at the end of the first loop. Use `std::getline` so you won't have this problem:

```
if (getline(ss, Name) && getline(ss, car) && ss >> weight && getline((ss >> std::ws).ignore(), hairColor))
{
    cout << "Name is: " << Name << endl;
    cout << "car is: " << car << endl;
    cout << "weight is: " << weight << endl;
    cout << "Hair color is: " << hairColor << endl;
    cout << "Eye color is: " << eyeColor << endl;
    cout << "Favorite color is: " << favoriteColor << endl;
}
```